# How to have sample page for each new register users in a membership website

Tags: plugins, pages, shortcode, users, profiles

I have a membership website where my users can create their own page. I have some pages which I want every new users to have them (duplicate my page as their own).

For every new users I have to instruct them about how to copy past my page & publish them. Is their any way or plugin or codes by which whenever some one register in my website he will have some pre-published page.

It is like new WordPress registration. When someone install WordPress 1st time, he always have 1 sample page. Like this is their any way to have such sample or copy of a page for new users.

Any helps will be highly appreciated.

Comment: hmmm breaking this down, I can see there are 2 separate questions, "How do I create a post/page?" and "How do I run code when somebody registers?"

Comment: Thank for comment. What I really want is when someone register in my website as a member, he will have 1-2 already published page (duplicate of some of my pages). So that he do not have to create new page by himself. I want to make it simple for them. So my question was is their any plugin or function.php snippets codes to make it easily.

Comment: So you need to create those pages automatically in code

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, is there any such codes.

Answer (score 2):

There's a hook called `user_register()` that you could use. It happens during the creation of the new user - right after they are added to the database and have an ID, but before the usermeta like first_name has been saved. You can then use `wp_insert_post()` to add the new post and assign them as the "author."

```
<?php
// When a user first registers, run our function
add_action('user_register', 'wpse_293428_create_user_post', 10, 1);
function wpse_293428_create_user_post($user_id) {
    // Set up a simple post array
    $sample_post = array(
        // Set to desired post type: post, page, etc.
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title' => 'Sample Post',
        // Post content can get much more complex if you need html etc.
        'post_content' => 'This is a test post',
        // Choose post status you want: could be a draft, or could be published
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        // Use the User ID that WP just created for this user
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        // Only if it's a Post, set Category - requires an array
        'post_category' => array(1)
    );
    wp_insert_post($sample_post);
}
?>
```

You may want to change what category(ies) the new post appears in, or if you switch to creating a Page make sure to remove `post_category`. Depending on your needs, filling in more complex `post_content` may get a bit tricky so start simple and then slowly build out what you want.

Comment: I tried, but it not worked. There was not any pre-published page. Anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: @Deb the code example above creates a post not a page, and demonstrates how you would create a post of type `post` on registration. Changing it to create a post of type `page` is rather trivial/ As I said elsewhere, answers will tell you how to do something, so that you understand the solution, they aren't copy paste fully baked solutions.

Comment: @TomJNowell So from above code, if I replace the 'post' with 'page', will it work.

Comment: Deb, this site is set up to provide ideas but often using those ideas involves manipulating the code yourself. As I already mentioned above, if you want to create a Page instead of a Post, you change the post type, and also remove the `post_category` line since categories do not apply to Pages. I would suggest trying the original code as-is first, and seeing if it does indeed create a Post. If so, then you can modify bit by bit until you reach your desired end goal.